# Table pagination with AngularJS and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a Rails application which uses AngularJS for displaying and asynchronously updating a list of objects (configured as AngularJS resources). Is there a simple way to server-side paginate this table?

Comment: so, list or table? nglist or ngGrid?

Comment: A table populated with ng-repeat.

Comment: you could combine a solution with this https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: I tried to use the angular-table gem ([link](https://github.com/ssmm/angular-table)) in order to obtain pagination ([link](http://ssmm.github.io/angular-table/examples.html)). The gem correctly display only a portion of my data, but the pagination component contains only 1 page link which is also disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) offers a way to paginate queries in Rails controllers and models. From the github README:

```
## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)

## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

You can customize the default page contents:

```
# for the Post model
class Post
  self.per_page = 10
end

# set per_page globally
WillPaginate.per_page = 10
```

And with Active Record 3 you can do things like:

```
# paginate in Active Record now returns a Relation
Post.where(:published => true).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')

# the new, shorter page() method
Post.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing pagination server side with #ngTasty
git : https://github.com/zizzamia/ng-tasty
docs : http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table-server-side